# p5.js Time Issue

Tags: time, p5.js, seconds

New to p5.js and trying to create a clock, a sliding clock ideally. I have successfully created a working clock and am now working on adding in the sliding effect. As of right now, I have run into a bug with time for the others, time-1 and time-2. Here is what happens: [Clock Bug 0-2,0-1,0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIxWu.png)

https://editor.p5js.org/miteshjethwa/present/zeYgP3rzx

Here is the code in case it is needed:

sketch.js:

```js
var myFont
var button
var activated
var myDesign

function preload () {
  myFont = loadFont("MajorMonoDisplay-Regular.ttf")
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER)
  
  fill('#000000')
  
  button = createButton("Show Date")
  button.position(10,10)
  button.size(100,25)
  button.mousePressed(pressFn)
  
  activated = false
}

function myDesign() {
    push()
  translate(width/2,height/2)
  
  textFont(myFont);
  
  //textSize(100)

  textSize(25)
    fill(255)
  text(nf(day(),2) + " " + nf(month(),2) + " " + year(), 0, 150)
    pop()
}

function pressFn() {
  if (activated) {
    activated = false }
      else {
        activated = true
      }
} 

function draw() {
  background(0);
  
  if (activated) {
    myDesign()
  }
  
  if (activated) {
    button.html("Hide Date")
  } else {
    button.html("Show Date")
  }
  
  translate(width/2,height/2)
  
  textFont(myFont);
  
  textSize(75)
  
  fill(255)
  
  text(nf(hour(),2) + " " + nf(minute(),2) + " " + nf(second(),2), 0, 0)
  
  fill(25)
  
  text(nf(hour(),2) + " " + nf(minute(),2) + " " + nf(second()-1,2), 0, -100)
  
  fill(12.5)
  
  text(nf(hour(),2) + " " + nf(minute(),2) + " " + nf(second()-2,2), 0, -200)
  
  //if (second() = 59) {
  //  second() = 00
  //}
  
}
```

style.css:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the desired outcome?

Comment: Sorry should have stated, wanting the bottom time to be the real-time and the one above to be 1 second behind real-time, then the one above that to be 2 seconds behind the real-time to create a sliding effect that is right now static, running into the issue where when seconds()=0 it shows 0-1 or 0-2 etc.

Comment: I believe I have a solution but am unsure how to put it into syntax properly:

if s=-01

let s=59

if s=-02

let s=58

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to just store the state of the time inside of an array. Without an array of storage, you would need to do a lot of math with modulus and ternary operators and possibly more things.

Here's a simple demo using JavaScript to control HTML elements:

```js
// you won't need this, this just gets the elements
const prev2 = document.querySelector("#prev2"),
  prev1 = document.querySelector("#prev1"),
  current = document.querySelector("#current");

//
//
//
//

let times = Array(3).fill(['','',''])

function draw() {
  if (second() !== +times[2][2]) {
    times.shift();
    times.push([hour(), minute(), second()].map(n=>n.toString().padStart(2, 0)));
  }

  // you would use text() here, like:
  // text(times[0].join`:`, x, y);
  prev2.innerText = times[0].join`:`;
  prev1.innerText = times[1].join`:`;
  current.innerText = times[2].join`:`;
}

//
//
//
//

// since p5 isnt working in snippets, this stuff below makes a mock version

setInterval(draw, 16.67);

function hour () {
  return new Date().getHours();
}

function minute () {
  return new Date().getMinutes();
}

function second () {
  return new Date().getSeconds();
}
```

```html
<p id="prev2"></p>
<p id="prev1"></p>
<p id="current"></p>
```

Comment: https://editor.p5js.org/miteshjethwa/sketches/s1eto41Op

Comment: [object Object]

Comment: Ok so I attempted adding this in, to the HTML and JS, tried with and without my time section and came out with the result of [object Object], Also p5.js uses second() rather than seconds() for example so I adjusted them and I can't figure out why it says [object Object] and as to why it won't work in general I've spent all day and have been unable to put this together. Thank you for the help, really appreciate it